# What am I doing wrong with my if statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm porting a website I had build already for another project into React and wanted to set a state for my navbar and was trying to set up my conditionals to render my pages first but it keeps throwing syntax error

I tried changing the {} enclosing to if to () to see if that did anything. I also tried wrapping my if inside {()} and nothing

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    page: 0,
  }
  setPageChange = () => {
    setState({ page: props.key })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        {if (this.state.page === 1) {
          return (<Products />)
        } else if(this.state.page === 2) {
          return (<Contact />)
        } else {
          <Landing />
        }}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where does `props.key` comes from?

Comment: You can not put if else inside return statement. plz move it above return statement and take component in a variable and just print it return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't matter with the bracket, you can try this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    page: 0,
  }
  setPageChange = () => {
    setState({ page: props.key })
  }

  renderContent() {
    if (this.state.page === 1) {
      return <Products />;
    } else if(this.state.page === 2) {
      return <Contact />;
    } else {
      return <Landing />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        {this.renderContent()}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using function is far better than using nested ternaries, in both readability and maintainability +1

Comment: yeap, totally agree. For me, I would separate the `renderContent()` logic into a new file/class and handle the rendering there. That way is more modular.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) like,

```
{this.state.page === 1 ? <Products /> : this.state.page === 2 ? <Contact /> : <Landing />}
```

Comment: We have to avoid nested ternary operators. Check this link below.
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary

Comment: @FrozenICE Yes. You are correct. We should avoid *nested ternary expressions* when we have very complex code, which creates difficulty to understand the code. We can use for simple 1 liner code.

Comment: @ravibagul91 even simple code it's best not to use nested ternary

Comment: The first line of rule says *Nesting ternary expressions can make code more difficult to understand.*  and that is why we should avoid to use it. @JeeMok can you please tell me exactly what is the problem with this approach. Why we should avoid it? Is there any side effects?

Comment: @FrozenICE Can you help me understand the problems of using this approach?

Comment: @ravibagul91 not trying to start an argument here, imo, for me, it is mainly the readability that might cause unnecessary confusion, another example `1 === 1 ? 1 : 2 === 2 ? 2 : 3`  which can be slightly improved by a bracket  `1 === 1 ? 1 : (2 === 2 ? 2 : 3)` . I hope you get my point, but feel free to follow what's best for you, if you're working only for your own project. cheers!

Comment: @JeeMok Thanks. I am not starting any argument, I am really trying to understand why is the rule. BTW thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this would be:

```
  render() {
    const { page } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        { (page === 1) && <Products /> }
        { (page === 2) && <Contact /> }
        { (page !== 1 && page !== 2 ) && <Landing /> }
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for this is like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    page: 0,
  }
  setPageChange = () => {
    setState({ page: props.key })
  }

  render() {
    const { page } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        {page === 1 && <Products />}
        {page === 2 && <Contact />}
        {page !== 1 && page !== 2 &&
          <Landing />
        }
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternate way is to use a mapper object and default value

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    page: 0,
  }
  setPageChange = () => {
    setState({ page: props.key })
  }

  renderContent(val) {
    let obj = {
      1: Products,
      2: Contact,
    }
    return obj[val] || Landing
  }

  render() {
    let Component = this.renderContent(this.state.page)
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
          <Component />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demo

```js
function NavBar() {
  return <h1>Hello Navbar</h1>;
}

function Footer() {
  return <h1>Hello, Footer</h1>;
}

function Landing() {
  return <h1>Hello, Landing</h1>;
}

function Contact() {
  return <h1>Hello, Contact</h1>;
}

function Products() {
  return <h1>Hello, Products</h1>;
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    page: 1,
  }
  setPageChange = () => {
    setState({ page: props.key })
  }

  renderContent() {
    if (this.state.page === 1) {
      return <Products />;
    } else if(this.state.page === 2) {
      return <Contact />;
    } else {
      return <Landing />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        {this.renderContent()}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```